# How do I make a HTTPS call to AWS hosted backend

Tags: javascript, java, amazon-web-services, https

I have a simple mint javascript website making a call to backend server to POST some data from the form. The backend is Java jar file that is hosted on AWS elastic beanstalk.

Everything was working smoothly until I added https to the chain. 
What was done: 
1) Enabled SSL certificate to the web hosting
2) Created SSL certificate for my AWS instance
3)  Set up a classic load balancer and configured it to listen on port 443 and redirect requests to my instance port

The problem is this set up is simply not working. 
I am still able to access my backend through HTTP connection, but when I'm trying to use HTTPS I get the following:
Chrome gives me "et::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID"
Firefox gives me "Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https:***. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)"

At the moment I keep my CORS policy at allowOriging("*") and out of ideas what might be wrong.

Will be super grateful for any help. Thanks in advance, folks!

Comment: it looks like your server has not enabled CORS. Check it - i guess that AWS Servers won't reject CORS requests

Comment: But as I said, I'm still able to access it, if I go HTTP instead of HTTPS, so it seems like CORS is enabled. Or I'm getting you wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It might mean you are trying to serve some resources across both protocols, hence HTTPS and HTTP. You can't make a request from HTTP to HTTPS.